# How to send JSONArray to PHP server using Volley?

Tags: java, php, android, android-volley

I'm fairly inexperienced with Android programming and am having issues sending a JSONArray to my PHP server. I am using the following code to generate the JSONArray from my cursor:

```java
public JSONArray matrixJSON(){
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT columnID,rowID,value FROM Matrix WHERE PolicyID=" + curPolicy,null);

        JSONArray resultSet = new JSONArray();
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
            int totalColumn = cursor.getColumnCount();
            JSONObject rowObject = new JSONObject();
            for (int i = 0; i < totalColumn; i++) {
                if (cursor.getColumnName(i) != null) {
                    try {
                        rowObject.put(cursor.getColumnName(i),
                                cursor.getString(i));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        Log.d(TAG, e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            }
            resultSet.put(rowObject);
            cursor.moveToNext();
        }

        cursor.close();
        return resultSet;

    }
```

I believe I am misunderstanding how to properly send data via JsonARrayRequest. Here is the following code that I am using to send the data.

```java
public void sendData(JSONArray data) {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "http://10.123.20.180:8080/insertmatrix.php";
        JsonArrayRequest dataReq = new JsonArrayRequest(Request.Method.POST, url, data,
                response -> Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(),
                error -> Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()){
            @Override
            protected Response<JSONArray> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {

                if (response.data == null || response.data.length == 0) {
                    return Response.success(null, HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
                } else {
                    return super.parseNetworkResponse(response);
                }
            }
        };
        queue.add(dataReq);


    }
```

Instead of sending the data, I am left with a blank array. The cursor to JSONarray function is working properly as I can see in debug, but the php server is receiving a blank array. I assume there is some essential functions I am missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by switching my array into a string and then using a `StringRequest` to send the data.

Updated function:

```java
public void sendData(JSONArray data) {
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        String url = "http://10.123.20.180:8080/insertmatrix.php";

        String json = data.toString();

        StringRequest dataReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,url,response -> Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show(),
                error -> Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()){
            @Override
            protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
                Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String,String>();
                params.put("data",json);

                return params;
            }

        };

        queue.add(dataReq);


    }
```